# Babel C++ blocks have incorrect indentation

Tags: org-mode, org-babel, indentation, c++, c

When using a C++ source block in org-mode, the indentation doesn't match that of the C++ major mode.

Viewing the source block in the org file:

[image: Indentation in org file]

Viewing the same code in a C++ mode buffer or using `org-edit-special`:

[image: Indentation with C++ major mode]

In the major mode buffer, the indentation is correctly treated as spaces as per my configuration

```
(use-package cc-mode
  :config
  (defun my-c-mode-common-hook ()
    (c-set-offset 'substatement-open 0)
    (setq c++-tab-always-indent t)
    (setq c-basic-offset 4)
    (setq c-indent-level 4)
    (setq tab-stop-list '(4 8 12 16 20 24 28 32 36 40 44 48 52 56 60))
    (setq tab-width 4)
    (setq indent-tabs-mode t))
  (add-hook 'c-mode-common-hook 'my-c-mode-common-hook))
```

whereas in the source block they are treated as 6 characters wide tabs. The way the indentation is treated simply switches between being a tab and being 4 spaces, when I switch between the `org-edit-special` environment and the plain org file.

The relevant part of my configuration:

```
(setq org-src-preserve-indentation nil)
(setq org-src-tab-acts-natively t)
(setq org-edit-src-content-indentation 0)
```

```
(org-babel-do-load-languages
  'org-babel-load-languages
  '((emacs-lisp . t)
    (C . t)))
```

I would be fine with the editing being wonky in the org file, but I would very much prefer the display of the code being correct. How could I accomplish this?

Answer (score 0):

That’s because an org buffer is in `org-mode`, not `c++-mode`. This is expected; the indentation rules for org files are nothing like those of C++ files, and the indentation rules don’t magically change just because you’re inside of a source block.

You can run `org-babel-expand-src-block` (bound to `C-c C-v v` by default) to open the content of the source block in a new buffer. That new buffer will be in the correct mode for the language. Once you’re done editing it, hit `C-c C-c` to save it back to your org file.

Edit:

Now I see that you are indenting your files with *tab characters*. Each buffer has a single value for `tab-width` which controls how wide a tab is. You can’t have tabs be a different size in one part of the buffer than another.

Comment: If I have a python source block, the behaves as I expect, 4 spaces. Why is this behavior different than the C++ block if the indentation rules are not affected by the fact that you are inside of a source block? There must be a way to affect how indentation is treated inside of a source block depending on the language used in the source block.

This is what I expect the setting `org-src-tab-acts-natively` to accomplish. As per the documentation: 
"If non-nil, the effect of TAB in a code block is as if it were issued in the language major mode buffer."

Comment: To add, my concern is not mainly on the editing part, but on how it is displayed in the org buffer. Even if I edit the source block with `org-babel-expand-src-block` and get the desired indentation while editing, when saving it back to the file, it saves it with 6-character wide tab characters instead.

Comment: Oh, you’re using tab _characters_.

Comment: I don't want to use tab characters. If I edit C++ code in a major mode buffer, the tab key inserts 4 spaces. If I edit Python code in a major mode buffer, it also inserts 4 spaces. If I edit C++ code in a source block, the tab key inserts a 6-wide tab character. If I edit Python code in a source block, the tab key inserts 4 spaces. 

If I edit C++ code using `org-edit-special`, use the tab key to insert 4 spaces, and then save the code back to the org-mode buffer, the 4 spaces gets converted into a 6 character wide tab key again.